# Does WebRTC makes sense for a a real time app to support many concurrent users?

Tags: websocket, webrtc

I want to build a real time online multiplayer game. After researching WebSockets and WebRTC, I've come to the conclusion that WebRTC is exactly what I need if I was building a p2p game. However, WebRTC seems like its not meant for handling group conferencing. This is because if there are "n" users, there will be "n-1" streams of data. This is obviously not scalable. There are smart ways to circumvent this, like using https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-videobridge and other solutions. But essentially it seems that WebRTC is meant for one-to-one communication. Most of the tutorials out there serve that purpose, not group conferencing.

Questions -

1. I've read that Google Hangouts and Facebook Messenger use WebRTC for their group video chats but how exactly have they solved this problem?
2. Are server based Websocket implementations like uws viable for real time communications? (due to added latency)
3. Is there any plan to address group conferencing from the WebRTC or is WebRTC just not meant for this use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does make sense but not with multiplexing. If you want to build **big real-time conferences** - then you need a server in the middle for doing optimization (optimize for only the 4-5 users that are speaking loudly and put the others in `listen mode` for ex). Twilio has nice paid services around this. You can copy their model - they explain their approach a lot on their YouTube channel - but it's a ton of work to get it that reliable.

Comment: are you asking about adding a voice/video communication channel to a game or exchanging game data between players? Two different kinds of servers are needed.

Comment: Both. I would need to transfer audio and game data. Not video (for now).